# Mercurial repository max commit count?

Tags: mercurial

I'm using Mercurial for versionning, and it now takes a while to push/pull to a repo. So I am wondering:

- Is there any limit on how many commits a Mercurial repository can have? Can a repository have millions of commit?

Bonus question:

- Do push, commit and pull operations have a linear complexity? Or will every commit/pull/push takes a longer time as changetsets count increase? (like, commiting the Nth changeset takes N ms instead of a fixed 100ms)

Comment: Do you commit binary files? That's probably the reason your push/pull operations are taking so much time.

Comment: Push/pull complexity should depend primarily on the number and size of commits that need to be transfered and the number of heads a repository has. The total number of commits in a repository should not affect it (unless you have hooks installed that do O(reposize) operations or something like that).

Comment: @robert Some few pngs, like ~1000 while having like ~4000 php/js/css files, so somehow 20% of the files count, and also about ~20% of the files size